# How to exclude specific Integers from arc4random

Tags: swift, arc4random

I want to get a random number with `arc4random_uniform()` but excluding the numbers from an array like this

```
var numbersArray = [8,15,10,3,7]
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20)
```

If the `arc4random_uniform()` gives me any number from the `numbersArray` I want it to get a new number that is not from the `numbersArray`

I tried this

```
func getRandomGroup() -> Int {
    for numbers in numbersArray {
        if numbers == randomNumber {
             var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20)
        }
    }
    return randomNumber
}
```

But it did not seemed to work

Comment: Just repeat creating a random number until you get one that is not in the array ... did you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a "write my code for me" site. It is a site where you get help with specific coding problems. Try to solve this yourself, and if you are unable, post what you tried and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: I'm sorry @DuncanC, I forgot to write the code that I make to solve it I updated the post with the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift 2.0

```
var numbersArray = [8,15,10,3,7]
var randomNumber : Int
repeat {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(20))
} while numbersArray.contains(randomNumber) 
print(randomNumber)
```

In Swift 1.x it is do while

Comment: Good answer (voted). You beat me to it. (Although, since Swift 2.0 is in very early Beta, I'd probably show the Swift 1.2 syntax as the primary and list Swift 2.0 syntax as an alternative.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try it:

swift 2.

```
var numbersArray = [8,15,10,3,7]

func getRandomInArray(arr: [Int]) -> Int{
    let indexRandom = Int(arc4random() % UInt32(arr.count))
    return arr[indexRandom]
}

getRandomInArray(numbersArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
var numbersArray: [UInt32] = [8,15,10,3,7]

func getPseudoRandom() -> UInt32 {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20)
    if numbersArray.contains(randomNumber) {
        return getPseudoRandom()
    }
    return randomNumber
}

for _ in 0..<20 {
    print(getPseudoRandom())
}
```